# Get current heap usage of app process

Tags: java, android, memory

I would like to find out how much memory my Android App is currently using in order to prevent `OutOfMemoryExceptions`. I know that you can find out the maximum Memory that one application can use by calling `Runtime.maxMemory();` - and on some devices this is pretty low (24MB), so memory will be an issue for my game.

When I call `Runtime.totalMemory()` in the onCreate() method **before** starting my Game Engine, I get ~23MB - and calling this **after** starting my Game Engine and after loading a bunch of (small) Bitmaps into memory, I get ~25MB heap usage. It's possible that the 2MB difference is exactly the usage of my GameEngine (it's still an early version), but I'm not 100% sure.

Nevertheless, this memory usage would already exceed the maxMemory limit of some low memory android devices. I'm pretty sure that parts of the application runtime which are not actively created by my application (e.g. shared libraries) do not count for the maxMemory limit; but apparently they do count for the totalMemory stat.

So how can I know for sure how much memory my app uses and still has before the maxMemory limit is reached?
`Runtime.freeMemory()` doesn't help either.

Comment: "...in order to prevent OutOfMemoryExceptions" -- `OutOfMemoryError` is only loosely tied to how much memory your app is using. The far more common problem is that your heap is fragmented, and while you may have lots of heap space available, nothing is big enough for your particular request. "I know that you can find out the maximum Memory that one application can use by calling Runtime.maxMemory()" -- I am not aware that this value has any relevance on Android. The official approach to determining your heap limit is to call `getMemoryClass()` on `ActivityManager`.

Comment: "Nevertheless, this memory usage would already exceed the maxMemory limit of some low memory android devices" -- my guess is that those values include memory shared with other Android app processes, such as the Dalvik runtime engine, Android framework class library, and so on. Again, I am not aware that any `Runtime` value is necessarily useful for an Android app developer.

Comment: @CommonsWare: The `maxMemory()` is almost always the same as `getMemoryClass()`, afaik. I've seen this on several Stackoverflow threads when max memory per app was discussed.

Comment: And I see where Google is using it in some samples, which also helps. That being said, I don't know of a great way to find out your remaining heap space, and since you can fail a memory allocation anyway due to fragmentation, I doubt that it will help much. We use `getMemoryClass()`/`maxMemory()` to help size caches, but then rely on weak and soft references to ensure that caches can get flushed if needed to help try to fulfil allocation requests.

Comment: Isn't heap automatically defragmented when memory becomes an issue? I would have guessed so, since otherwise it's going to be very tough to build a nice app with high quality bitmaps and a nice performance with low disk usage.

Comment: "Isn't heap automatically defragmented when memory becomes an issue?" -- no. On Android 5.0+ devices, ART has a moving garbage collector, but it only operates while the app is in the background. Prior to that, Dalvik had no moving collector, and so the heap is always fragmented. "otherwise it's going to be very tough to build a nice app with high quality bitmaps and a nice performance with low disk usage" -- correct. However, there are countless image-loading libraries with integrated scaling and caching that can help (Picasso, Universal Image Loader, etc.).